# gcc with MacPorts (select not changing the right link)

Tags: macos, gcc, macports

I followed the instructions for installing GCC 4.7 with MacPorts.
http://www.ficksworkshop.com/blog/14-coding/65-installing-gcc-on-mac

Everything seems to work, but 'select set' is not updating the right (AFAIK) link.

```
$ gcc -version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2: no input files

$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

$ ls -l /usr/bin/gcc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 Jul 14  2013 /usr/bin/gcc -> llvm-gcc-4.2
```

According to the guide, Macports installs to /opt/local/bin.  Select is changing that link accordingly:

```
$ ls -l /opt/local/bin/gcc
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  25 Sep 28 12:20 /opt/local/bin/gcc -> /opt/local/bin/gcc-mp-4.7
```

But make is calling /usr/bin/gcc.
Can I manually change the symbolic link or is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `/opt/local/bin` earlier in your `PATH` than `/usr/bin`. As I recall, the installer package for MacPorts modifies your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile to do this for you. However, that will only affect shells which are started **after** installing MacPorts.

So, the first thing to try is to simply open a new shell and see if things are working as you expect there.

Comment: Also check make is not calling /usr/bin/gcc directly rather than relying on the PATH

Comment: MacPorts gave some nice comments in ~/.profile.

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2014-09-18_at_15:32:54: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.

However, this is the output of 'echo $PATH'
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin/

So, it's still picking up /usr/bin/gcc first.

Comment: Mark

How do I confirm that make is using PATH and not calling it directly?

Comment: EDIT: Okay changing the PATH manually to have /opt/local/bin works.  So, Make is doing it right.  Now to fix the PATH on each login.

Comment: Do you have a ~/.bash_profile file? If so, it takes precedence over ~/.profile.

Comment: I do, and I edited it to read
PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH instead of
PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/bin

Seems to work well enough.